# iOS Convert NSData to NSDictionary returns nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

In My code I want to convert NSData to NSDictionary but it returns nil I don't know what mistake I made,I Used NSJSONSerialization for convert data to dictionary, The NSData was received from server response.

Here I show my Full code what I am trying.

```
-(void)SendPushNotification:(NSString*)getUrl :(NSMutableDictionary *)getData withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSDictionary *))completionBlock
{
    NSError *error;

NSLog(@"dict val: %@",getData);
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:getData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];// Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *postData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *postLengthas = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getUrl]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:100.0];

NSString *chkRegDevice= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"bearer"];
NSString *strfds=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bearer %@",chkRegDevice];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLengthas forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:strfds forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configg=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession*sessionn=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configg delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURLSessionDataTask *taskk=[sessionn dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *responce,NSError *error){
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        completionBlock(nil);
    }else{
        NSError *jsonError;
        NSString *clientDetail = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"clientDetail: %@", clientDetail);
        NSData *objectDataaaaa = [clientDetail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectDataaaaa options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
        NSLog(@"json %@",json);
        if (![clientDetail isEqualToString:@"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."]) {
            if (completionBlock) {
                completionBlock(json);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            completionBlock(nil);
        }
     }
  }];
 [taskk resume];
}
```

Here the following response I get to convert NSData to NSString.

> "{\"multicast_id\":8856529321585625357,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1534479035021563%1dbdaa031dbdaa03\"}]}"

Comment: Which is the NSData received from server response in your code? Can you show me the full code? I want to know which method you are using for HTTP request.

Comment: I added full code@VinuJacob

Comment: Okay, Try this code in your else condition.


    NSError *e = nil;
    NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
    NSLog(@"Response Dict%@",JSON);

Comment: It also returns (null).@VinuJacob

Comment: Did you check this Request in PostMan

Comment: Yes In PostMan I got the response like..""{\"multicast_id\":8856529321585625357,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1534479035021563%1dbdaa031dbdaa03\"}]}"" @VinuJacob

Comment: Okay, do one thing, when you get the success in postman you can get the code from PostMan. Try that code in your project. Maybe the issue is regarding the way you are sending the request in form-url encoding or row data.

Answer (score 0):

Pass NSData object(`data`) directly to  `JSONObjectWithData`.
Also, to check the error, you can print `jsonError`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSString* str = your string data;
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *decodeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
   encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSDictionary *dict = [self dictionaryWithJsonString:decodeString];

/////////////////////

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithJsonString:(NSString *)jsonString {
    if (jsonString == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *err;
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData

    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                      error:&err];
    if(err) {
        return nil;
    }
    return dic;
}
```

Comment: I will try your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
NSError* error;
NSData *objectDataaaaa = [clientDetail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectDataaaaa
                                                 options:kNilOptions 
                                                   error:&error];
NSLog(@"JSON DICT: %@", json);
```

Comment: @b-saravana-kumar have you checked this?