# iOS Terminating app due to uncaught exception ' this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key success.'

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

In my code I have to get the value from NSDictionary but it crashes and the crash issue is,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x155000fa0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key success.'

Here I show the the code what I am trying.

```
NSLog(@"finalValNotify is: %@", finalValNotify);
if (finalValNotify) {
   int successResult=[[finalValNotify valueForKey:@"success"]intValue]; ====>This line app crashed
   if (successResult==1) {
      NSLog(@"finalValNotify is: %d", successResult);
   }
}
```

Here I show the printed NSDictionary value:

> finalValNotify is: {"multicast_id":5704734283387573862,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1534486056437155%1dbdaa031dbdaa03"}]}

But I don't know the reason for why the crash was occur.

Comment: The error message states that `finalValNotify` is a string, not a dictionary. And generally don't use KVC methods like `valueForKey` for getting values from JSON dictionaries. Use `objectForKey` or – more recommended – key subscription like `finalValNotify[@"success"]`

Comment: But I declared like "NSDictionary *finalValNotify;"@vadian

Comment: It is possible convert that NSString to NSDictionary.@vadian

Comment: The type of the declaration is irrelevant. It counts what the actual type is. A JSON string can be deserialized with `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: How to serialized JSON string to NSDictionary.@vadian

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjective-c%5D+NSJSONSerialization). (De)Serializing JSON is one of the most frequently asked questions. And you were even using `NSJSONSerialization` in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889036/ios-convert-nsdata-to-nsdictionary-returns-nil)

Comment: I got this **this class is not key value coding-compliant** from your content. I think you need to check your data format.

Answer (score 0):

If `finalValNotify` is your NSDictionary then use as -

```
int successResult = [finalValNotify[@"success"] intValue];
```

Comment: The problem here is that `finalValNotify` is an `NSString`, not an `NSDictionary`

Comment: thats why i used `if` before writing the statement @MichaelHulet

Comment: Fine, but this is provably not the case, which makes this answer unrelated to the question